# Redirect from localhost:8080 to localhost:3000 after Post request

Tags: spring, facebook, reactjs, spring-mvc, spring-social

I am trying to make a form submit post request to my backend for user authentication with Facebook, I get redirected to facebook and I log in to facebook. I am successfully verified and I returned the user object(as configured in my backend). My backend Facebook auth is done following the [spring social tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/), I also followed Geoffroy's spring social login tutorial: geowarin.GitHub dot io/social-login-with-spring.html. My frontend React.Js code(runs on localhost:3000) looks like:

```
const auth_url = "/connect/facebook";
<form className="signin__form" action={auth_url} method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="user_friends" />
    <button type="submit" className="signin__form-btn">
    SIGN IN WITH FACEBOOK
    </button>
</form>
```

My package.json proxies the connect/facebook response to localhost:8080 and looks like:

```
{
...
"proxy": {
    "/connect": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  },
...
}
```

What I expect to see:

on localhost:3000

```
{React view components}
```

What I see:
on localhost:8080

```
{
  user: info
}
```

My question is how can I go back to localhost:3000 after the backend redirects are finished and should I make another method in the backend so I can make an ajax get a request in the frontend to fetch user info rather than sending the JSON object back. I am not sure how to redirect back to 3000 after the spring.social handshake is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can change your controller

The header to redirect on client

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth_url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void login(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Location", "http://localhost:3000");
}
```

OR return redirect URL from controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth_url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView login() {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:http://localhost:3000");
}
```

Alternatively I would suggest to submit the form by AJAX and process onSuccess without leaving localhost:3000

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! I tried doing an AJAX post request with fetch and axios library, but they both did not like the 302 redirect response I get back when I'm sent to Facebook for authentication by the auth controller in the backend. Is there a way to wait for the redirection to finish and then receive the response?